# neither window.resolveFileSystemURI() nor window.requestFileSystem exist when using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, devexpress

I just started to use Phonegap and unfortunately I'm stuccoed in an issue. an Image is captured successfully using camera api but I want to move the picture from cache to a selected folder of my android device aswell. I looked all over the internet and some people use window.resolveFileSystemURI but it doesnt exist in my project.

```
TestCamera.home = function (params) {
//Callback function when the picture has been successfully taken
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // Get image handle
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

    // Unhide image elements
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageData;
    alert(imageData);
    //movePic(imageData);

}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = $('#largeImage');
    largeImage.css('display', 'block');
    largeImage.attr('src', imageURI);
}
function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: TestCamera.destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
function movePic(file) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError);
}

//Callback function when the file system uri has been resolved
function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    //new file name
    var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "EasyPacking";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
        //The folder is created if doesn't exist
        fileSys.root.getDirectory(myFolderApp,
                { create: true, exclusive: false },
                function (directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, successMove, resOnError);
                },
                resOnError);
    },
resOnError);

}

//Callback function when the file has been moved successfully - inserting the complete path
function successMove(entry) {
    //I do my insert with "entry.fullPath" as for the path
    alert(entry);
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
var viewModel = {
    capturePhoto: function (e) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: TestCamera.destinationType.FILE_URI

        });
    },
    capturePhotoEdit: function (e) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 20,
            allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: TestCamera.destinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    },
    photoLibrary: function (e) {
        getPhoto(TestCamera.pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);
    },
    photoAlbum: function (e) {
        getPhoto(TestCamera.pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);
    }
};

return viewModel;
```

};

!window[resolveFileSystemURI()] returned true, 
Am i missing a file or something?
Any help would be really appreciated :)
Daan Helsloot

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add file plugins to your project first:

```
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

By the way I have another solution to your issue, you can just retrieve the base64 of the captured image using the following code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});
```

then save base64 encoding to any directory you want

Comment: Hi Hazem, First of all thanks for your help! can i add those plugins without using a commandline tool? I already tried the other solution you provided but that didnt work unfortunately :(

Comment: @DaanHelsloot: try to use the command line tool because it is the best and to be 100% safe